# Calling a function (eg. Date) inside ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm new to Angular and this question most likely is a trivial one!

```
<div ng-controller="index">
        <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead style="font-weight: bold;">
                        <td>Update Time</td>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="doc in allDocuments | searchFilter:srcStr">
                                <td>{{doc.updateTime}}</td>
                        </tr>
                </tbody>
        </table>
</div>
```

The above html renders as follows:

**Update Time**

1419421439570

1418552500904

1418368139999

1417703400456

But these values are actually time stamps (which come from the server as long values) and I want to render them as proper dates (e.g. MM/DD/YYYY) by converting them to JavaScript Date objects. Is there anyway I can do so inside the `ng-repeat` block itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can user

`date` filter form angular.

[See doc.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)

`<td>{{doc.updateTime | date}}</td>`

Comment: Thanks for the quick help! `<td>{{doc.updateTime | date : 'medium' }}</td>` worked great for me!

Answer (score 0):

By using the built-in filter, try the below:

```
<td>{{ doc.updateTime | date: 'MM/DD/YYYY' }}</td>
```

**Other option:**

If you want to re-use the format in many places, instead of hard-coding every where, you can use `$scope`

In controller:

```
$scope.dateFormat = 'MM/DD/YYYY';
```

Then in html:

```
<td>{{ doc.updateTime | date: dateFormat }}</td>
```